# Why does my Rails 4 scope show as method_missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something obvious here but my scopes in this model yield a method_missing error when I attempt to call them. For instance in a new Rails console,

```
 inspection = Inspection.find(1)
 inspection.created_before

 NoMethodError: undefined method `created_before`
```

I've copied the example from the Rails Guides expecting I was making a syntax error. I've simplified it so that it didn't need a variable. I've commented everything but the class definition and the scope makes no difference. Other models use a scope but this one I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong. I've made it a class definition to see if that was but it's not working. The other methods in this class are working fine, it appears. I've spent all day on this and am not seeing it and seek help.

inspection.rb

```
VARIANCE_ITEMS = 60
MISC_ITEMS = 70
REVIEW_ITEMS = [20, 30, 40, 50]


class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify

  include RollbackLogger
  include SurveyHelper

  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :survey

  has_many :scores, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores

  has_one :cash_variance
  has_one :message, dependent: :destroy

  scope :created_before, -> { where("created_at < ?", Time.now) }
  scope :recent_of_same_type, ->(survey){ where(survey_id: survey.id).order("inspection_date desc").limit(5) }



  before_create do |inspection|
    begin
    inspection.name = Survey.find(inspection.survey_id).name

    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      inspection.name = 'blank'
    end
    unless inspection.inspection_date?
      inspection.inspection_date = inspection.created_at
    end
  end

  after_create do |inspection|
    items = Item.where(survey_id: inspection.survey_id)
    items.each do |item|
      Score.create(score_item: item.high_score, item_id: item.id, inspection_id:     inspection.id, multiplier: item.scoring)
    end
    survey = Survey.find(inspection.survey_id)
    if survey && survey.name == "Loss Prevention"
      REVIEW_ITEMS.each do |x|
        3.times do |score|
          Score.create!(item_id: ("#{x}#{score}").to_i, inspection_id: inspection.id, multiplier: 1)
        end
      end

    end

  end



protected

  def message_check
    actual_score = grand_total(self.scores, :score_item, :multiplier)
    hi_score = high_score_total(self.survey.items, :high_score)

    unless self.message.nil?
      if (actual_score < hi_score) && (self.message.emailed)
        self.message.update_attributes(flag: FLAGS[2]) if self.message
      elsif (actual_score < hi_score) && (self.message.emailed == false)
        self.message.update_attributes(flag: FLAGS[1]) if self.message
      else
        self.message.update_attributes(flag: FLAGS[0]) if self.message
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes are defined at the class level not the instance level. So your scope would be callable with

```
Inspection.created_before
```

`scope` is just a `class_method` creation `method` it will define these methods for you as

```
scope :method_name,->(variables_accepted){method body}
```

which translates into

```
class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.method_name(variables_accepted)
      method body
  end
end
```

This will return all `Inspection`s created before right now which would be all of them. Pretty much the same as calling `Inspection.scoped`

If you want to find items created before a certain instance you could scope it like this

```
scope :created_before_id, ->(id){ where("created_at < ?", find(id).created_at)}
```

Called as

```
Inspection.created_before_id(1)
```

This will return all the `Inspection`s created before the creation date for a given `id` **Note** this will raise if the `id` cannot be found. You could alter it like so

```
scope :created_before_id, ->(id){ 
                    inspection = find(id)
                    inspection ? where("created_at < ?", inspection.created_at) : scoped   
}
```

Which will return all `Inspection`s prior to a given `id` or all the `Inspection`s if it cannot find one by the given `id`.

If you want to call it from an instance level then you would need to define an `instance_method` like so

```
def created_before
  Inspection.where("created_at > ?", self.created_at)
end
```

Which will return all `Inspection`s prior to a given instance just like you are doing now.

```
Inspection.find(1).created_before
```

Comment: Yes, I see this more clearly. I was trying to reconcile how a similar scope in the related model Score was being used. ie: inspection.scores.my_cool_scope worked as expected but wouldn't on Inspection itself.

Comment: @sam452 the reason that works is because of scope chaining. You are in essence calling `Scores.where(inspection_id: YOUR_INSEPCTION_ID).my_cool_scope` so as you can see it still remains at the class level through an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. Your current implementation creates and instance variable of an `Inspection` thus leaving the higher level. I added a few things to my answer for additional clarity.